# How does Menumaker select categories?

Tags: gentoo, openbox, menu

I am using Gentoo with Openbox and would like to switch which categories the mmaker (Menumaker) program puts programs into for my menu. But I am unsure of how/where Menumaker pulls this data from, and my Google skills seem to be failing me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

This data is defined in the applications' `.desktop` files. You can find them in `/usr/share/applications`.
More information is available in the [Desktop Menu Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/) at freedesktop.org